# Merging two PDF pages on top of each other

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am looking for a way to merge the content of two pdf pages.
It could be a watermark, an image or whatever.

The scenario is as follows:
I have a Word-addin that allows the user to create different templates for different customers based on several template forms. For each new customer, the user can provide a new letter paper containing header image / logos and footer. This shall be applied anyhow at runtime. Could be an image that is loaded directly into the header of the template (then I would need to render pdf to image, for the letter paper will mostly be provided as pdf-file) or when exporting the document (merging letter paper as background).

But the template shall not be accessible by the user, so this must be done programmatically.

So far, I tried Pdfsharp library, which does not support neither the version of my provided backpapers, nor the version of my documents created in Word 2007.
iTextSharp seemed very promising, but I could not manage to merge the contents so far.
I also tried pdftk.exe, but even when i ran it manually from command line, I got the error: "Done. Input errors, so no output created."

It does not matter how it is handled, but the output matters.

I forgot to mention, there is a whiteline created in the Word-template for archiving purposes, so this part may not be added as image or it has to be added afterwords into the output document.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StampStationery.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=StampStationery), a sample from the [Webified iTextSharp Examples](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/) which essentially are the C#/iTextSharp versions of the Java/iText samples from the book [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/), does show how to add the contents of a page from one PDF document as stationery behind the content of each page of another PDF.

The central method is this:

```
public byte[] ManipulatePdf(byte[] src, byte[] stationery)
{
  // Create readers
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
  PdfReader s_reader = new PdfReader(stationery);
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Create the stamper
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
    {
      // Add the stationery to each page
      PdfImportedPage page = stamper.GetImportedPage(s_reader, 1);
      int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
      PdfContentByte background;
      for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      {
        background = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);
        background.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
      }
    } 
    return ms.ToArray();   
  }
}
```

This method returns the manipulated PDF as a `byte[].`

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising, I will just check that!

Comment: Just to clarify: works exactly as i wanted! Read files as byte[], call this function, save bytes - done! :)

Comment: Great! Please be aware, though: If your documents are large, you may want to use a different `PdfReader` constructor (which does not require the whole PDF in memory) and use some file stream instead of the `MemoryStream` as output. Otherwise your resources might be insufficient, especially if you call that method from multiple threads concurrently.